# How do I add multiple textFields to a PDF using this method?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults to save text entered into multiple UITextFields.  I want to display the text on a PDF.  Can I use the following method to handle each field and add it to the PDF?  Right now in my example you can see how I am adding a "name" field.  Any tips is appreciated!

```
 +(void)drawText
{
   NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString * nameString = [prefs stringForKey:@"name"];

   CFStringRef stringRef = (CFStringRef)nameString;

   // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter
   CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
   CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

   CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(30, 0, 300, 60);
   CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
   CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

   // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
   CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
   CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
   CGPathRelease(framePath);

   // Get the graphics context.
   CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
   // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
   CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

   // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
   // the current transform prior to drawing.
   CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 100);
   CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

   // Draw the frame.
   CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

   CFRelease(frameRef);
   CFRelease(stringRef);
   CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change method like given below for dynamic text in textField:

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString *)value index:(int)index
{
   //NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   //NSString * nameString = [prefs stringForKey:@"name"];

   CFStringRef stringRef = value; //(CFStringRef)nameString;

   // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter
   CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
   CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

   CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(30, (index*70), 300, 60); //for horizontal textfields
   CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
   CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

   // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
   CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
   CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
   CGPathRelease(framePath);

   // Get the graphics context.
   CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
   // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
   CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

   // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
   // the current transform prior to drawing.
   CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 100);
   CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

   // Draw the frame.
   CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

   CFRelease(frameRef);
   CFRelease(stringRef);
   CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

Use like this as i assume u have array of values for adding textfield:

```
for(int i=0;i>[arrOfValues count];i++)
{
   [YourControllerName drawText:[arrOfValues objectAtIndex:i] index:i];
}
```

Comment: Can this be used to place text in custom locations?